# INNER JOIN on greatest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am wondering if it is possible to innner join on the greates value.

So for example

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicle v
INNER JOIN VehicleCost vc ON v.VehicleWeight > vc.WeightFrom AND c.VehicleWeight < vc.WeightTo
```

But if v.VehicleWeightTotal > v.VehicleWeight I want that to replace v.VehicleWeight on the inner join. So potentially this could be a different join for each vehicle.

How would I go about doing that check within the join?

Sample:

```
tblVehicle
VehicleId  VehicleWeight VehicleWeightTotal 
1               12              15
2               1               8
3               16              20

tblVehicleCost
WeightFrom    WeightTo  Dollars
0               5         1
6               11        8
12              16        9 
17              20       15
```

So:

```
Vehicle 1 = 9
Vehicle 2 = 8
Vehicle 3 = 15
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results. It is not a good idea to put logic in joins in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements can be more simply expressed as:

> *use the greater of `VehicleWeight` and `VehicleWeightTotal` when joining*

This is how you express that in SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicle v
INNER JOIN VehicleCost vc 
   ON (case
         when VehicleWeightTotal > VehicleWeight then VehicleWeightTotal
         else VehicleWeight
       end) between vc.WeightFrom AND vc.WeightTo;
```

I took the liberty of changing your range check to use `between`, but if it's not OK to match on the value equalling the range limits - ie using `>=` and `<=` in your query - then just repeat the `case` statement for each side of the range.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM Vehicle v
INNER JOIN VehicleCost vc ON 
  case when v.VehicleWeight > v.VehicleWeightTotal then v.VehicleWeight
       else v.VehicleWeightTotal end > vc.WeightFrom 
  AND case when v.VehicleWeight > v.VehicleWeightTotal then v.VehicleWeight
       else v.VehicleWeightTotal end < vc.WeightTo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a derived table to define a column for the greater weight between `VehicleWeight` and `VehicleWeightTotal` as a CASE expression. That way you wouldn't have to repeat the long expression in your join condition:

```
WITH GreaterWeights AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    GreaterWeight = CASE
      WHEN VehicleWeightTotal > VehicleWeight THEN VehicleWeightTotal
      ELSE VehicleWeight
    END
  FROM Vehicle
)
SELECT *
FROM GreaterWeights v
  INNER JOIN VehicleCost vc ON v.GreaterWeight > vc.WeightFrom
                           AND v.GreaterWeight < vc.WeightTo
```